# pandas - finding most recent (but previous) date in a second reference dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have two dataframes and for one I want to find the closest (previous) date in the other.

**If the date matches then I need to take the previous date**

`df_main` contains the reference information

For `df_sample` I want to lookup the `Time` in `df_main` for the closest (but previous) entry. I can do this using `method='ffill'` , but where the date for the `Time` field is the same day it returns that day - I want it to return the previous - basically a `<` rather than `<=`.

In my example `df_res` I want the `closest_val` column to contain `[ "n/a", 90, 90, 280, 280, 280]`

```py
import pandas as pd

dsample = {'Index': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     'Time': ["2020-06-01", "2020-06-02", "2020-06-03", "2020-06-04" ,"2020-06-05" ,"2020-06-06"],
     'Pred': [100, -200, 300, -400 , -500, 600]
    }

dmain = {'Index': [1, 2, 3],
     'Time': ["2020-06-01", "2020-06-03","2020-06-06"],
     'Actual': [90, 280, 650]
    }

def find_closest(x, df2):
    df_res = df2.iloc[df2.index.get_loc(x['Time'], method='ffill')]
    x['closest_time'] = df_res['Time']
    x['closest_val'] = df_res['Actual']
    return x

df_sample = pd.DataFrame(data=dsample)
df_main = pd.DataFrame(data=dmain)

df_sample = df_sample.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df_sample['Time']))
df_main = df_main.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df_main['Time']))
df_res = df_sample.apply(find_closest, df2=df_main ,axis=1)
```

[image: tables]

Comment: can you give the desired output as a dataframe? From your post I understeand that df_res is not what you want.

Comment: Use pd.merge_asof and set allow_exact_matches=False

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.merge_asof` (make sure 'Time' is indeed a datetime):

```
pd.merge_asof(dsample, dmain, left_on="Time", right_on="Time", allow_exact_matches=False)
```

The output is:

```
   Index_x       Time  Pred  Index_y  Actual
0        1 2020-06-01   100      NaN     NaN
1        2 2020-06-02  -200      1.0    90.0
2        3 2020-06-03   300      1.0    90.0
3        4 2020-06-04  -400      2.0   280.0
4        5 2020-06-05  -500      2.0   280.0
5        6 2020-06-06   600      2.0   280.0
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, we can do a Cartesian product of both your dataframes, then filter out the exact matches, then apply some logic to figure out the closest date.

Finally, we will join your extact, and non exact matches into a final dataframe.

```
s = pd.merge(
    df_sample.assign(key="var1"),
    df_main.assign(key="var1").rename(columns={"Time": "TimeDelta"}).drop("Index", 1),
    on="key",
    how="outer",
).drop("key", 1)


extact_matches = s[s['Time'].eq(s['TimeDelta'])]
non_exact_matches_cart = s[~s['Time'].isin(extact_matches['Time'])]


non_exact_matches = non_exact_matches_cart.assign(
    delta=(non_exact_matches_cart["Time"] - non_exact_matches_cart["TimeDelta"])
    / np.timedelta64(1, "D") 
).query("delta >= 0").sort_values(["Time", "delta"]).drop_duplicates(
    "Time", keep="first"
).drop('delta',1)
```

---

alot to take in the above variable, but essentially we are finding the difference in time, removing any difference that goes into the future, and dropping the values keeping the closest date in the past.

```
df = pd.concat([extact_matches, non_exact_matches], axis=0).sort_values("Time").rename(
    columns={"TimeDelta": "closest_time", "Actual": "closest val"}
)


print(df)

    Index       Time  Pred closest_time  closest val
0       1 2020-06-01   100   2020-06-01           90
3       2 2020-06-02  -200   2020-06-01           90
7       3 2020-06-03   300   2020-06-03          280
10      4 2020-06-04  -400   2020-06-03          280
13      5 2020-06-05  -500   2020-06-03          280
17      6 2020-06-06   600   2020-06-06          650
```